# removing labels from JFree pie chart

Tags: charts, jfreechart

Im new to JFree charts, im created a piechart using JFree chart. Now i want to remove the labels from the chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
plot.setLabelGenerator(null);
```